# I need help resetting a secondhand iPad 3rd gen (A1403)

Tags: ipad, itunes, apple-id

I bought the iPad on eBay and received it today. It was sold as untested, but the old Apple ID is still linked to it.

I tried to use the steps on the support page [If you forgot your iPhone passcode, use your Mac or PC to reset it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306) but none of them have worked.

At the moment, it's asking to connect to a network or iTunes, which it also can't do. Networks fail to connect and iTunes wants the old Apple ID and password I don't have.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the seller and asking if they have the info you need?

Comment: I did try, but there was no way to contact. Usually there's an option to message through eBay, but not for this seller.

Comment: Try to return (via eBay) it and let this be a lesson learned:   “Untested”  = “it’s not working.”

Comment: The seller actually just refunded the purchase when I asked about the activation lock. So I have both the money and the locked out iPad.